com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 11 Application error en-US
Im using jsc 0.2.17,

private ChannelSftp setupJsch() throws JSchException {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.addIdentity(SFTP_PRIVATE_KEY_PATH, SFTP_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSPHRASE);
        JSch.setConfig("server_host_key", JSch.getConfig("server_host_key") + ",ssh-rsa");
        JSch.setConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", JSch.getConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms") + ",ssh-rsa");
        Session jschSession = jsch.getSession(SFTP_USERNAME, SFTP_HOST, SFTP_PORT);
        jschSession.setPassword(SFTP_PASSWORD);
        jschSession.setConfig(config);
        jschSession.connect();
        return (ChannelSftp) jschSession.openChannel("sftp");
    }

public void getFiles(String sftpDirectoryPath) throws JSchException, SftpException, IOException {
       
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
        LinkedHashMap<String, byte[]> fileBytesMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        try {
            channelSftp = setupJsch();
            channelSftp.connect();

            log.info("Fetching files from : "+ sftpDirectoryPath);
            Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> files = channelSftp.ls(sftpDirectoryPath);
       }
}

Im able to get files for 1-2 times, but later on it start to give
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 11 Application error en-US,
Whenever i restart the application, it works for some requests and later I get this error and it remain till I restart.
2024-10-24T13:02:53.181+05  0 ERROR 13364 --- [ scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchSessionDisconnectException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 11 Application error en-US
 at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:1316) ~[jsch-0.2.17.jar!/:0.2.17]
 at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java  39) ~[jsch-0.2.17.jar!/:0.2.17]
 at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:19  ~[jsch-0.2.17.jar!/:0.2.17]
 at com.abc.xyz.util.SFTPUtil.setupJsch(SFTPUtil.java:79) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
 at com.abc.xyz.util.SFTPUtil.getFiles(SFTPUtil.java:93) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
 at com.abc.xyz.listener.firm.firmH2HListener.getBankFolderFiles(firmH2HListener.java  6) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
 at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:56  ~[na:na]
 at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.18.jar!/:6.0.18]
 at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.18.jar!/:6.0.18]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java  05) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java  05) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]
2024-10-24T13:02:53.181+05  0 ERROR 13364 --- [ scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

com.jcraft.jsch.JSchSessionDisconnectException: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 11 Application error en-US
 at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:1316) ~[jsch-0.2.17.jar!/:0.2.17]
 at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java  39) ~[jsch-0.2.17.jar!/:0.2.17]
 at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:19  ~[jsch-0.2.17.jar!/:0.2.17]
 at com.abc.xyz.util.SFTPUtil.setupJsch(SFTPUtil.java:79) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
 at com.abc.xyz.util.SFTPUtil.getFiles(SFTPUtil.java:93) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
 at com.abc.xyz.listener.firm.firmH2HListener.getBankFolderFiles(firmH2HListener.java  6) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
 at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:56  ~[na:na]
 at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.18.jar!/:6.0.18]
 at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.18.jar!/:6.0.18]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java  05) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java  05) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]
t com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:1316) ~[jsch-0.2.17.jar!/:0.2.17]
 at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java  39) ~[jsch-0.2.17.jar!/:0.2.17]
 at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:19  ~[jsch-0.2.17.jar!/:0.2.17]
 at com.abc.xyz.util.SFTPUtil.setupJsch(SFTPUtil.java:79) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
 at com.abc.xyz.util.SFTPUtil.getFiles(SFTPUtil.java:93) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
 at com.abc.xyz.listener.firm.firmH2HListener.getInboxFolderFiles(firmH2HListener.java:41) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
 at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:56  ~[na:na]
 at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84) ~[spring-context-6.0.18.jar!/:6.0.18]
 at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-6.0.18.jar!/:6.0.18]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java  05) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java  05) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]

this is the trace I get
What can I do to solve this error?

Post JSch log file + Does server-side log file show anything useful? + Isn't this a standard behaviour of the server? That it disconnects clients after certain time...

I have don't have access to server side log.
